# Asymptotic Expression for the number of solutions to linear Diophantine equation.

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory, linear-diophantine-equations, analytic-combinatorics

Consider the the general linear diophantine equation
$$\sum_{i=1}^{k}a_ix_i =n $$
with $a_i\geq 1, n\geq 1$ and $x_i\geq 0.$

Then the generating function that counts the number of solutions to this equation is 
$$F(x)=\prod_{i=1}^{k}\left(\frac{1}{1-x^{a_i}}\right) = 1+\sum_{n\geq 1}a(n)x^{n},$$
where $a(n)$ is the number of solutions to the linear Diophantine equation. Due to [Schur](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur%27s_theorem#Combinatorics) we have that if $\gcd(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_k)=1$ then 
$$a(n)\sim \frac{n^{k−1}}{(k − 1)!a_1a_2 ··· a_k}$$
as $n\to \infty.$

However, I am curious to know if there is a general asymptotic expression for $a(n)$ with perhaps no restrictions on the coefficients $a_i$ of the equation. I tried to see if I could mimic the proof of Schur's theorem to come up with something, but because in the general case we do not know which pole of $F$ has the highest multiplicity, it is hard to guess the answer.

Any ideas in this regard will be much appreciated.

Comment: If $\gcd(a_1,\ldots,a_n)=d>1$, then we must have $d\mid n$ to get $a(n)\neq 0$, and division by $d$ brings you back to $\gcd=1$. (The above is "almost" the general case.)

Comment: Do you suggest that $a(n)\sim \frac{(n/d)^{k−1}}{(k − 1)!a_1a_2 ··· a_k}$ where $d=\gcd(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_k)$?

Comment: $a(n)\sim\frac{(n/d)^{k-1}}{(k-1)!(a_1/d)\ldots(a_k/d)}=\frac{n^{k-1}d}{(k-1)!a_1\ldots a_k}$, *only when* $d\mid n$.